# Is there a way to create a curve when launching a gameobject to the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is what I have tried so far:
I create a raycast and if it hits an object on layer 8 (the layer in which objects need to be launched to the player), I call the SlerpToHand() function.

```cs
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward * raycastLength, out hit))
        {
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.layer == 8)
            {
                // Launch object to player
                SlerpToHand(hit.collider.transform);
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside of SlerpToHand(), I set the object's position to Vector3.Slerp(), that vector being created from values in the hit object.

```cs
    private void SlerpToHand(Transform hitObj)
    {
        Vector3 hitObjVector = new Vector3(hitObj.transform.position.x, hitObj.transform.position.y, hitObj.transform.position.z);

        hitObj.position = Vector3.Slerp(hitObjVector, transform.position, speed);
    }
```

But the result of this is all wrong, the object just gets teleported to the player's hands. Is Vector3.Slerp() not a good way to curve an object to the player? For context I am trying to recreate Half-Life: Alyx's grabbity gloves. There is still some work to do with the hand gestures but I am just trying to get the object curve down. Help is much appreciated, let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

See unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html):

public static Vector3 Slerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float t);

Here, t is a normalized position between two input values. It means, if t = 0, result will be exactly first value. If t = 1, result will be exactly second value. If t = 0.5, result will be the middle between two values.

So, usually, you need to call Slerp every Update, step by step increasing t from 0 to 1. For this, usually Time.deltaTime used (which equals the time between updates). For speed control, multiply your speed by Time.deltaTime.

```
Update()
{
    if (t < 1)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime * speed;
        hitObj.position = Vector3.Slerp(startPosition, endPosition, t);
    }
}
```

...and in this case, for start moving, you just need to set t = 0. Probably, you have to implement your own logic here, but this should show the idea.

In addition:

- Slerp used to interpolate between vector directions, for positions use Lerp.
- Consider use [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/) plugin - its free and powerful for such cases.

Comment: Hi yes, that worked. Thank you for your answer. Why would I use DOTween?

Comment: DOTween is powerful tool for a wide range of animation, made from your code. Want to move something? Rotate? Bounce, jump? Fade in and out, and a lot of specific things for different components - this all can be easily done with DOTween. Animations, which are called "tweens", are controllable - you can pause, stop, restart, reuse them. There is a powerful path tool, which allows you to create paths from points on a fly, and launch objects across these paths. A ton of different easing options, including custom one, based on an animation curve. Very good performance.

Comment: For example, in your case, you shouldn`t store any additional t variable, and call some function every update - you just need a single line of code to move some object to some position with given speed and easing, and then you have a callback, when its done.

Comment: Something like this: `myObjectTransform.DOMove(endPosition, duration).SetEase(Ease.InOutSine).OnComplete(() => Debug.Log("Object arrived to destination"));`

Comment: That sounds very useful. I suppose it could be very useful in animating UI too! Thank you